Do we need the axiom of separation to show $\{x\}$ exists?
According to this post, we need the axiom of separation to show that $\{x,x\} = \{x\}$.
I struggle to see why this is so. It seems to me the axiom of pairing allows us to construct a set $X$ such that
$$y\in X \iff (y = x \lor y = x)$$
yet the latter condition is equivalent in first-order logic to $y=x$, hence
$$y\in X \iff y = x.$$

Things don't exist in a vacuum. You need to tell us what the other axioms first. Pairing isn't always an axiom, since pairing itself is a consequence of Replacement and Infinity, or Replacement and Power Set and Empty Set, or Replacement and Power Set and Infinity. And so on.

Pairs axiom: $∀x∀y∃z∀w[w ∈ z ↔ (w = x \lor w = y )]$ is enough.
$\{ x \}$ is simply $\{ x,x \}$.
As per comment below, we can use a weaker form of the Pairs axiom:  $∀x∀y∃z[x∈z ∧ y∈z]$, in which case we know that the set $z$ has $x$ and $y$ as elements, but we cannot rule out the fact that there are others.
Thus, we need Separation with formula $(t=x ∨ t=y)$ to carve out the pair from $z$.

Doesn't the need for separation depend on whether the axiom of pairing is formulated in the elaborate form $$\forall x\forall y\exists z\forall t[t\in z\leftrightarrow(t=x\lor t=y)]$$ or in the simple form $$\forall x\forall y\exists z[x\in z\land  y\in z]?$$
